# Django models how to use select_related

Tags: django, django-models

I'm not 100% how this works being new to Django. I want to list all contact first_name's that belong to my Group. I only load the group to save hitting the DB twice I was told to use  select_related to achieve this. below is what I have tried. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

model.py

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user")

class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

part of m view.py

```
 if id:
        # If we have an id try and get it and populate instance.
        group = get_object_or_404(Group.objects.select_related(), pk=id)
        show_upload = True
        # If we have an instance check that it belongs to the login.
        if group.user != request.user:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

The part of the template I'm trying to list contact first_name

```
 {% for item in group.contact %}
        <tr>

        {{ item.first_name }}


        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
group_instance.contact_set.all().values_list('first_name',flat=True)
```

See the [example](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter10.html) on this page about related objects. (section "Accessing Foreign Key Values")

[select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) is used for JOIN on the database level.

Using of `get_object_or_404` is described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404).

```
def my_view(request):
    my_object = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=1)
```

is equivalent to

```
def my_view(request):
    try:
        my_object = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
    except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
```

Comment: not really what I was after, I'm trying to do this in the context of select_related.

Comment: @MarkO get_object_or_404 expects to get Model class.

Comment: As contact in not a FK in the group table how does group know about it?

Comment: @MarkO select_related is used differently: if you want to get the contact group (contanct.group.name for example) without going to the database every time, and not vice versa.